# React-i18n Trans Component with translations that contain HTML tags not working

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I'm trying to use [`react-i18next`](https://react.i18next.com/) with a translation json that contains some HTML tags, like this:

```json
// en.json
{ "welcome": "Welcome to our site, <strong>{{name}}</strong>" }
```

In my React component, I want the string to be rendered like this.

> Welcome to our site, **John**

Using the `useTranslation` function normally printed the string literally without interpreting it as HTML, like `Welcome to our site, <strong>John</strong>`.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next'

const App = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation()

  return(
    <div>{t('welcome', { name: 'John' })}</div>
  )
}
```

I replaced it with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and it was rendered correctly.

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: t('welcome', { name: 'John' }) }}></div>
```

However, I want to avoid using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` if possible. I read in the docs that you can use something called Trans components for translations with HTML tags.

Docs: [Using for `<br />` and other simple html elements in translations (v10.4.0)](https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component#using-for-less-than-br-greater-than-and-other-simple-html-elements-in-translations-v-10-4-0)

But I'm confused about how to use them, since the examples they show seem to be for replacing placeholder tags like `<1>` with actual tags like `<br />`. Is there a way to use Trans components (or some other method that doesn't use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`) to get translated strings to be interpreted as HTML?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, you're doing it wrong.

```
return (
  <Trans i18nKey="welcome">
    Welcome to our site, <strong>{{name}}</strong>
  </Trans>
)
```

And your JSON file should look like:

```
"welcome": "Welcome to our site, <1>{{name}}</1>"
```

The reason you use `<1>` is because `Trans` breaks up your string in to an array, so in this case it's: `["Welcome to our site, ", "<strong>{{name}}</strong>"]`
https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component#how-to-get-the-correct-translation-string

Comment: This answer confused me for a long time because I still didn't know how to replace `{{ name }}` with the actual value (`John`). I learned that you can do `<strong>{{name: 'John'}}</strong>` instead of `<strong>{{name}}</strong>` in the trans component for this purpose.

Comment: `
const name = 'John'
return (
  <Trans i18nKey="welcome">
    Welcome to our site, <strong>{{name}}</strong>
  </Trans>
)
`

Comment: Make no sense to me at all, where translation come into play?

Comment: The translation text is pretty much hardcodes, so where is the point?

Comment: @Guichi I just had the same question, so posted the [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71641812/2516673)

Comment: @Fappaz looks better

Comment: Yeah that good solution but if our json file itself has this kind of string Welcome, &lt;strong&gt;User!&lt;/strong&gt  then it will show Welcome, &lt;strong&gt;User!&lt;/strong&gt  on UI side.

So, is there any way to convert &lt; to < and &gt; to > ???

Answer (score 17):

Posting here because this is the first search result on the interwebz, and none of the answers worked for my case.

My translation JSON looks like this:

```json
"readOnlyField": "<0>{{- key}}:</0> <1>{{- value}}</1>"
```

The only way I managed to make it work was to use `Trans` like this:

```js
<Trans
  i18nKey="readOnlyField" // the key in your JSON file
  values={{ // The variables in your i18n entry from the JSON file
    key: "Storage",
    value: "2TB SSD",
  }}
  components={[<strong />, <i />]} // The component at index 0 (<strong />) will be parent of <0> ({{- key}}), and so on...
/>
```

So it would look like this:

> **Storage:** *2TB SSD*

---

Edit: You can also declare the components as a map, like so:

```json
"fullName": "<primary>{{- lastName}}:</primary>, <secondary>{{- firstName}}</secondary>"
```

```
<Trans
  i18nKey="fullName"
  values={{
    lastName: "Doe",
    firstName: "John",
  }}
  components={{
    primary: <strong />,
    secondary: <i />
  }}
/>
```

Comment: This is called interpolation. https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/interpolation

Comment: For me, this was also the only thing that worked.

Comment: The best example I could find.. Thank you!

Comment: Yep, this is the one that worked for me. The example on the website looks batsh*t crazy, not sure if the double brace is a nextjs thing, but it doesn't compile with the documentation example, plus the indexes didn't start from 0 which also made it not work. Thanks for this one.

Comment: Thank you for posting. Only the solution with the array worked for me, not the mapping.

Answer (score 3):

I just posted an answer to a similar problem i could solve but in **React Native**, should work in **React** as well:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70112582/9506908

````
// render
<Trans i18nKey="yourTranslationKey" components={{ link: <Text onPress={() => console.log('do something')}}} /> }} />

// translationFile
{...
 "yourTranslationKey": "Please <link>Click me</link>",
...}```
````

Comment: Only answer that I think is valid when you are working with multiple languages!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [the `Trans` component](https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component#trans-props) around your `<div>`. If you also want to pass some more complicated components you need to **pass the components as a prop** in the `Trans` component and **use their index as an intermediary HTML tag**. Then **also pass the translations in the options object** in the `t` function and use them both in your translation string.

```
// package.json
    ...
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^7.0.1",
    "i18next-http-backend": "^2.1.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.5",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-i18next": "^12.1.5",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    ...
```

#### In your component.

```
// src\App.js
<Trans
  t={t}
  components={[
    <span className="badge bg-primary"></span>,
    <span className="badge bg-success"></span>,
  ]}
>
  <p>
    {t("message", {
      somethingInsideBadge: `Some ${variable} inside the badge`,
      somethingElseInsideBadge: `Some ${variable} inside the badge`,
    })}
  </p>
</Trans>
```

#### Then in your translation file:

```
// public\locales\en-US\translation.json
{
  ...
  "message": "<strong>This is badge number 1:</strong> <0>{{somethingInsideBadge}}</0> <i>and badge number 2:</i> <1>{{somethingElseInsideBadge}}</1>"
  ...
}
```

### Result

[image]