# How to render component as a param using i18n-js in react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, localization, i18n-js

I am using [i18n-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n-js) for locales and translations. I am trying to render a react-native component using interpolation.

Following is the code for reference,

```
// Translate function (exposed using custom hooks)
const translate = useCallback((key, config) => i18n.t(key, config), []);
```

```
// locale key with variables to be interpolated
"tnc_text": "Accept {{topUpTnC}} and {{dealsTnC}} to proceed"
```

```
// Code which uses translate
<Text>
  {translate(
    'tnc_text', {
      topUpTnC: <Text
        style={{color: 'blue'}}
        onPress={() => Linking.openURL('https://google.com')}>
        Top-Up Terms and Conditions*
      </Text>,
      dealsTnC: <Text
        style={{color: 'blue'}}
        onPress={() => Linking.openURL('https://example.com')}>
        Deals Terms and Conditions
      </Text>,
  })}
</Text>
```

I am expecting something like this:

> Accept [Top-Up Terms and Conditions*](https://google.com) and [Deals Terms and Conditions](https://example.com) to proceed

But instead, I am getting this:

> Accept [object Object] and [object Object] to proceed

Couldn’t find anything in the documentation. Is there a way to replace variables with components in i18n-js?

Answer (score 3):

I got the same question and couldn't find an answer yet ...

maybe the Trans-Component could help:

https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component

Edit: This is maybe a good explanation
[React-i18n Trans Component with translations that contain HTML tags not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61268001/react-i18n-trans-component-with-translations-that-contain-html-tags-not-working)

**Second Edit:**
I could **solve** the Problem with following code:

```
// render
<Trans i18nKey="yourTranslationKey" components={{ link: <Text onPress={() => console.log('do something')}}} /> }} />

// translationFile
{...
 "yourTranslationKey": "Please <link>Click me</link>",
...}
```

Found it on [github](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/issues/833#issuecomment-496531179) :)

[This](https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component#alternative-usage-which-lists-the-components-v11.6.0) is the official documentation about it.